# Render Pipeline

Tags: unity-game-engine, pipeline, render

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQL39.png)

While the Render Pipeline is running, suddenly two images appeared on my game screen, one appearing further away and the other one bright as it seems. Despite my efforts, I couldn't get my game screen back to normal. What can I do?

I want the bright image to disappear and merge into a single image.